# Javascript to PHP else if ": ?" operator conversion

Tags: javascript, php, ternary-operator

I have never encountered this in javascript thus far although I am aware : ? means else if. I am having trouble figuring out how to lay it out in PHP. Here is what I did - where am I going wrong if it is wrong?

JSCRIPT

```
var midparams = dparams2.isramped() ? dparams2 : DailyParams.avg(dparams1, dparams2);
```

PHP

```
$midparams = $dparams2->isramped() if $dparams2 = $midparams else $DailyParams->avg($dparams1, $dparams2);
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea that PHP allows `if` and `else` in the middle of an expression like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got 2 options. 1st one is almost the same as JavaScript

```
$midparams = ($dparams2 -> isramped()) ? $dparams2 : $DailyParams->avg($dparams1, $dparams2);
```

The second one is more trivial:

```
if ($dparams2 -> isramped()) {
    $midparams = $dparams2;
} else {
    $midparams = $DailyParams->avg($dparams1, $dparams2);
}
```

First one says: midparams will be dparams if statement before is true, or $DailyParams->avg($dparams1, $dparams2) if it is not. Second is the same thing but in a more straight forward fashion.

Comment: Thank you for putting it into code form for myself - I have been reading up on the ternary operator but couldn't quite grasp it until this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$midparams = $dparams2->isramped() ? $dparams2 : $DailyParams->avg($dparams1, $dparams2);
```

Or this:

```
if($dparams2->isramped()) {
  $midparams = $dparams2;
} else {
  $midparams = $DailyParams->avg($dparams1, $dparams2);
}
```

You can read more about the ternary operator in:

> [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Answer (score 0):

This is called the ternary operator. It sets a variable based on a condition. In PHP, what it's saying (in pseudocode here) is:

```
setSomeVariable = (test condition) ? value if true : value if false;
```

So, if for example, you wanted to set the value of `$a` to 10 if the `$score` is greater than 100, or set `$a` to 0 if `$score` is less than or equal to 100, the code would look like this:

```
$a = ($score > 100) ? 10 : 0;
```

See the documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: @Pointy I removed that statement. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a ternary operator; it's used the same way in PHP as it is in JavaScript -

```
/* most basic usage */
$var = 5;
$var_is_greater_than_two = ($var > 2 ? true : false); // returns true
```

Straight from David Walsh's blog - http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

**Also note:** I think you're thinking about it a bit backwards -

It is *not* (**repeat, not**) used like this:

`$var = (assign this value) ? (if this is true) : (otherwise, assign this value)`

It *is* used like this:

`$var = (is this true) ? (then assign this value) : (otherwise, assign this value)`

---

**EDIT** Per @Pointy pointy-ing this out, there is a slight difference between how the statements are evaluated in JavaScript in PHP - See example #4 in the documentation. Although only a crazy person would write a long-winded unparenthesized ternary expression. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: No, it's not the same in PHP.

Comment: If the answer is wrong then explain how/why please.

Comment: PHP has a right-hand bias to interpreting a sequence of `? :` operations, while JavaScript (and pretty much every other language that has the construct) is left-biased.

Comment: @Pointy So they're the same unless you nest them without parenthesizing?

Comment: @Pointy are you talking about Operator Precedence? PHP is left-to-right and JS is right-to-left.

Comment: Nested ternaries are horrible, doing them without parentheses doubly so.

Comment: @Barmar I strongly disagree. It's a perfectly OK pattern in languages in which the grammar isn't wrong (ie, not PHP). When properly arranged it makes for readable, clean code.